# Euclidean problem of geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let the two quadrilaterals $ABCD$ and $EFGH$ been given:

[image]

Let's take these hypothesis:

$AD = EH$

$A\hat{B}D=A\hat{C}D=E\hat{F}H=E\hat{G}H$

$AC=EG$

The triangle $ABD$ is isosceles and equal to the triangle $EFH$

$A\hat{B}C + C\hat{D}A = E\hat{F}G+G\hat{H}E=180°$

$B\hat{C}D+ D\hat{A}B=F\hat{G}H+H\hat{E}F=180°$

Thesis: $CD = GH$.

Even if there are all these hypotheses I'm finding difficulties.
It's simple to prove that $B\hat{A}C= B\hat{D}C$ and $F\hat{E}G= F\hat{H}G$, but for some reason I can't prove that $B\hat{A}C=F\hat{E}G$, even if I know it's true.

Can you give me a hand? Thank you!

Comment: They are cyclic quadrilaterals that can be inscribed in the same  circle, $ABD=EFH$ and $EG=AC$, so you can overlap them.

Comment: @Benzio If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ABD=EFH$, since they both are isosceles, with the same base and the same opposite angle. $C$ belongs to the circumcircle of $ABD$ as well as $G$ belongs to the circumcircle of $EFH$, and since $EG=AC$, the two quadrilaterals overlap.